# Is there any reason why THIS character had no apparent interest in Moff Gideon?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the final sequence of the season 2 finale of *The Mandalorian*, there is a surprise rescue by

> Luke Skywalker, after receiving Grogu's call via Tython's "seeing stone" in
>  episode 2.06.

The character takes out all of the threatening Dark Troopers and then makes their way to the bridge of Moff Gideon's light cruiser where many of *The Mandalorian* characters remain!

They proceed to let Grogu say goodbye to Din Djarin, before presumably taking Grogu off to continue his training, which I understand is his primary purpose for coming.

However, Moff Gideon should be seen as a big threat, considering he is still operating under the guise of the former Empire, as fans know this is apart of Darth Sidious's plan to create The New Order and the Sith Empire.

***Is there any reason why THIS character wasn't concerned or even asked about the situation with Moff Gideon? Did they know Cara Dune would take him to the New Republic and/or believed they (Din, Cara, Bo-Katan, Fennic, and Koska) could deal with it on their own?***

I also understand that the *out of universe* answer would be, they didn't want to ruin the bittersweet moment, but I find it suspicious how silent and disinterested THIS character was about everything else going on there.

Comment: Just to note: Luke Skywalker *should be going around the galaxy and studying the history of Jedi at this time, and as extension of my Q, I would like to point out that the Dark Saber, should of also been a point of interest, unless he already knew the history of Tera Vizla/House Vizla.

Comment: He had his mind only on where he was and what he was doing.

Comment: @Mazura Ha! Well, that is his big problem as force user! :D

Comment: You mean the  Moff that was in shackles and in the custody of New Republic officer?

Answer (score 1):

### Because the character had more important things to do.

The character went to the ship to get Grogu, following the Force beacon call sent out at the ancient Jedi site on the mountain top in an earlier episode. In a universe very short on Jedi, uniting with Grogu was eminently important.

Moff Gideon may have been important if he was free and getting away, but he was lying on the ground in the custody of a Ranger of the New Republic. Pretty much the entire rest of the ship's complement--droid and human--had been taken care of at that point, so the character was fine with letting the ranger handle him while he took Grogu in his X-wing on Jedi business.

Comment: This may very well be part of the answer, but again I'm looking for a confirmation in a source that doesn't seem to exist yet. But also how did Luke know that Cara Dune was a Ranger and if he knows anything about Bo-Katan, that should concern him too! After what he went through with his father, I would think remnents of the EMPIRE ubducting force sensative beings would also be a priority, then again, maybe this is part of the hubris Luke spoke of in TLJ---but again, we don't know this, because there is no conformation of what Luke does and doesn't know in this scene.

Answer (score 0):

Said character only had one seat in his ship. Of course he could have killed Gideon but remember one of the major characters needed Gideon alive. Also, maybe Gideon plays a role in season 3 and Disney needed him alive.

> Also, they just killed Grogu by giving him to Luke, because all of Luke's pupils were massacred by Ben Solo shortly after, so... I guess that happened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am looking for something more definitive (with a source) other than speculation, which is what we try to do on this Movie & TV Stackexchange. I also was not asking about why Luke didn't kill Moff Gideon, but rather why he showed little to no interest in him.

Comment: As mentioned, Luke has not yet started his school (Kylo Ren is about 4-5 yrs old in this time frame!) & most likley, Grogu will end up with Din again during the 1st half of season three & remainder of The Mandalorian (because that's the show!). There is currently ZERO evidence that Ben Solo/Kylo Ren ever comes across Grogu, as that would be HUGE point of interest to Sidious/Snoke not included in the plots of the ST. We know Lando & Luke (TROS) go in search of answers and that most likely happened before Luke's school, since right after he goes into exile. Grogu most likely promps this search.

Comment: Especially since Rey will be born in about 5-6 years, which means her clone cast strand father is about to exist...

Answer (score -2):

I guess because THIS character is not part of the New Republic, but only a Jedi. His goal is to reestablish the Jedi Order, so he is only interested in Grogu.

Another reason might be, that he saw everything is under control, so he did not care because of the above-mentioned.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Movie TV Stack Exchange. The Mandalorian takes place @ 5 years after The Battle of Endor. Luke Skywalker had previously been on joint missions with New Republic (Shattered Empire mini series comic he worked with Poe Dameron's parents) to save Force Trees taken from Courascant temple. As for other source materials (Bloodline, Aftermath, The Legend of Luke Sky), and stated in my Q, this is a time when Luke is gathering information on the Jedi's past. He is about 5-10 years away from establishing a new school/Jedi order as Ben Solo is currently 5 yrs old.

Comment: @DarthLocke Are any of the comics, literature that you mentioned even canon?

Comment: @stackoverblown Yes!  All of them! Wouldn't of said otherwise! (will provide link). There are some minor discrepancies, such as Cobb Vanth's flashback is missing one major element from 'Aftermath', but that may be something that gets squared away in TBoBF. The Ahsoka novel also doesn't quite fit in anymore after CW S7, but everything else is pretty tight.  https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_books